# React <Link to={PATH}> is working but <Link to={{pathname:PATH}}> is not working (react-router-dom@5.3.0)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In React(with react-router-dom@5.3.0), `Link to={PATH}` works but `Link to={{pathname:PATH}}` does not work. I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
<Link to={`/chat_detail?name=${user?.name}&room=TestRoom`}>
  <div>TestBtn1</div>
</Link>

<Link to={{ pathname:`/chat_detail?name=${user?.name}&room=TestRoom` }}>
  <div>TestBtn2</div>
</Link>
```

1. **TestBtn1** works.
2. **TestBtn2** does not work. It shows a blank page and when I refresh on a blank page or directly enter the PATH in the address bar of browser, a page appears.

Is this a bug in `react-router-dom`?

Comment: i'm not sure if you can pass a component as state regarding the third example

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using `react-router-dom`'s version 6 which means that there is no `pathname` anymore.

According to [v5 to v6.3.0 migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/upgrading/v5)

> If you need to replace the current location instead of push a new one
> onto the history stack, use navigate(to, { replace: true }). If you
> need state, use navigate(to, { state }). You can think of the first
> argument to navigate as your  and the other arguments as the
> replace and state props. The Link component in v6 accepts state as a
> separate prop instead of receiving it as part of the object passed to
> to so you'll need to update your Link components if they are using
> state:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// Change this:
<Link to={{ pathname: "/home", state: state }} />

// to this:
<Link to="/home" state={state} />
```

Comment: Just FYI the `Link` component's `to` prop takes a [`To`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/router/history.ts#L98) object which can take a partial [`Path`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/router/history.ts#L35-L50) object, which includes a `pathname` string property. It was the `state` property that got moved.